# Network Error due to Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: civimember

All,

This post https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34829.0 describes the problem I just experienced. I was able to work around the issue by deleting www from the address in the address bar. Obviously, this is not a solution.

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your site is accessible via a single *canonical* hostname. Configure your webserver or CMS to redirect requests for other hostnames to the canonical hostname.

Currently your site is permitting people to browse on both *www.example.org* and *example.org*. While this works fine for Drupal/Joomla/WordPress, CiviCRM doesn't handle it well, and you'll see form submission errors or CORS issues.

By configuring a canonical hostname redirect, visitors hitting the wrong URL (eg *www.example.org/donate*) will be immediately redirected to the preferred hostname (eg *example.org/donate*).

The following settings must match:

- canonical hostname in your webserver or CMS configuration (varies by software in use)
- Base URL in CMS config (Wordpress: `wp_options` table; Drupal: `$base_url` in settings.php; Joomla!: _______?)
- `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` configured in `civicrm.settings.php`
- Resource URLS in civicrm admin section

Make sure to check both scheme (`http://` vs `https://`) and hostname (`example.org` vs `www.example.org` vs `www2.example.org`). Some modules or extensions (eg Drupal "secure pages") that offer redirects will also need to be considered/configured.

Configuring canonical hostname redirect is recommended for SEO as well as because it makes civicrm behave much better :)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I found the two lines in .htaccess that needed to be uncommented.