# Some users get a lifetime membership message when they try to renew

Tags: drupal, civimember

We have a rolling, one year membership set up and users can renew it manually. We do not have auto-renew set up and until we started hearing about this issue, didn't even know how to set up a "lifetime" membership. The membership gives them special member-only access to the site using the Drupal CiviMember role sync module once the membership status is "complete".

What happens is that a user goes to subscribe (and possibly renew) and will occasionally get a message on the contribution form that says, "You have a current lifetime membership which does not have to be renewed." On problem with this is that they don't have access to the member area until an admin goes in and subscribes them manually.

What could be causing this? The first time it was reported was a couple versions ago but we're on CiviCRM 5.10.4 and Drupal 7.64. I haven't been able to collect enough scenarios to determine if it's new users only or not.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

There is also a price set for the fee and we have coupon codes.

Edit:
I performed a search using search builder and discovered that 2,876 (roughly one third) who are members have no defined membership start date. I believe this issue is a residual affect of a [previous issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/member-since-and-start-date-arent-being-recorded-in-membership-details). The search was for all contacts who have the membership but the start date is null. Only 167 however, had no end date. 2,880 Have no "member since" date.

Edit: We're on 5.14.0 and Drupal 7.69 now. My client is still having this issue and it seems to be more frequent. I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you have any lifetime membership types configured?  If so, do they have any members? Do those provide any membership by relationship?

Comment: Go to `Administer > CiviMember > Membership Types` for an overview of the types including duration and related memberships

Comment: It's the only one. I added a screenshot of that also.

Comment: Ok, so it's not getting confused by 'real' lifetime memberships.  Is that error message exact?  I can't find it in a quick grep through the code.  Do you have any custom code/extensions/overrides that might be causing this?  Are users renewing via contribution page or webform?

Comment: Via a contribution form. No custom code that I'm aware of. The message is exact. When I inherited the project years ago there may have been some but I've reworked it completely since then and they didn't have any memberships set up yet or used yet.

Comment: I'm waiting to hear back from the client for more info but what I suspect is that if the user is put on "pending" status, such that their payment has tripped a security review and they try again in pending status, could they get this message as a red herring? I need to test this out to see.

Comment: We have seen "Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
You already have a lifetime membership and cannot select a membership with a shorter term." before but the client definitely had some Lifetime Membership Types. I note that your screenshots do not include a shot of //civicrm/admin/member/membershipType?reset=1. Could you add that to rule out the really obvious?

Comment: ah, i see you say you only have one Membership Type on that site. hmm. weird

Comment: At least one user was a first time subscriber.

Comment: But that that user tried multiple times and it's unclear and unlikely that he got this message the first time.

Comment: I've seen a similar message on a site that doesn't have lifetime membership.  It appears to be displayed to members that have opted to pay by recurring direct debit. I think the system may be interpreting a recurring contribution as a lifetime membership.

Comment: We have that turned off as well but I think it's for similar reason: there is a start date but no end date.

Comment: I'm still having this issue