# Membership on behalf of multiple organizations error

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Our client is an association of Pension Funds. Several fund administrators manage multiple funds. The managers need to renew the memberships of each fund under their control. The funds are the members, not the managers. However, after a support call, I logged in as a fund manager and received the following:

> You already have a lifetime membership and cannot select a membership
>   with a shorter term.

We have no lifetime memberships, but this fund administrator has 7 member funds in her portfolio. She renewed 2 before this error appeared. Also, one fund she tried to renew, was logged as one of her clients she had just renewed.

Essentially, she has clients A-F. She registered A and B, then C was assigned to B. Then I tried to login as her and got the error above. What have I done wrong or better yet, how do we fix this?

We are running 5.13.4 on Wordpress.

Comment: are you using Inherited Memberships?

Comment: when you say 'she registered A and B' i take it you mean "she went to a Contribution page and purchased a membership renewal On Behalf Of Org A, and subsequently for Org B". If so can you then explain in different language what is meant by "then C was assigned to B". eg do you mean, she then went back to the Contribution page, selected C from the set of options in the Org field (assuming they show here because she is (somehow) a current permissioned employer of all these Orgs) but the membership renewal she purchased ended up on Org B's record?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. You are absolutely correct. The contribution page for membership functioned for organizations A & B. When she tried to register organization C, it was assigned to Assigned to Organization B. When I logged in as the user, I received the error that a lifetime membership already exists, even though, there are no lifetime memberships configured on the site.

Comment: I really am not sure what else to suggest other than offering a quick consultation to see if a fresh pair of eyes can figure what is going on. Something is not set up as you need it.

Comment: It appears to be related to this issue: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28945/some-users-get-a-lifetime-membership-message-when-they-try-to-renew I would certainly be open to a consult.

Comment: Sure PM me or fire us a request via https://fuzion.co.nz/contact and we will see if we can dig in for you.

Comment: I have seen this issue when a member has a membership on the record with a status of 'cancelled' and then tries to renew. The 'Lifetime' error message appears even though the cancelled membership is of a different type. My work around was to set the status of the cancelled membership to 'expired' - this meant the membership could be renewed as normal.