# If membership status is 'Cancelled' get 'Lifetime' error message when trying to renew

Tags: civimember, error, renewals

I have seen this a couple of times in the past and wonder if others have seen it specifically linked to the membership status of 'cancelled'.

When a member tries to renew a membership that has been cancelled they get the error message:'You already have a lifetime membership and cannot select a membership with a shorter term.' regardless of their initial membership type.

The work around is to manually amend the status of the membership to expired, but this is obviously not a good work flow and frustrating for both users and admin.

Also possibly related:
[Membership on behalf of multiple organizations error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33538/membership-on-behalf-of-multiple-organizations-error)
[Some users get a lifetime membership message when they try to renew](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28945/some-users-get-a-lifetime-membership-message-when-they-try-to-renew)

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Whereabouts have you seen this bug? Just on your site or on others? If it is just on yours so far, do you have any extensions enabled? It would be good to rule out extensions and things specific to your site if possible. Would it be easy for you to re-create the issue on a demo site and provide steps to reproduce?

Comment: I have only seen it on my site, yes. We have the following extensions enabled: Localization Update1.0-beta,   iATS Payments 1.7, Fancy Searches 1.0, extendedreport 5.0,  CiviDiscount 3.8.1,  clickatell 4.1,  GoCardless Direct Debit Payment Processor 1.9.1, Phone Validator 1.2.   Happy to try and recreate on demo site - can you let me know where to do that? @michaelmcandrew Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15206#issuecomment-588903027) for this bug some time ago - but I didn't find time to follow up and improve it the way my reviewers requested.  If you feel comfortable applying this though, it will solve your problem for now.

Comment: Ah thank you, that's very useful - if it continues to be a big problem we will apply